# Vuetify 'ma-0/text-h1' classes not working on div

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="no_padding">
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols='6' class="no_padding">
        <v-sheet
          class='rounded-0'
          color='#1A237E'
          height='100%'
          dark flat
        >
        <div class="text-h1 ma-5"
          v-text="'Hello World'"
        >
        </div>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols='6' class="no_padding">
        <v-img alt="Vue logo" :src="require('../assets/man_coding.jpg')">
        </v-img>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

On the div inside the v-sheet element i have added typography and spacing classes but nothing is happening and no errors are being thrown.
I'm looking at the documentation but can't seem to find an explaination...
Can someone help with this, the text is just in plain small text with no styling and there are no margins on the div.